# New to C programming, wondering why my program ends after if else statement

Tags: c

I am trying to create a program that will tell you when you should shave (for a school project). When I try to run the next if-else statements with user input, the program ends before letting me put input. Can anyone assist?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    
    char userChoice;
    char noShaveNovember = '\0';
    char participation;
    int numInteractions;
    int voteShave;
    char mustache[36] = "Shave everything but your mustache.\n";
    char fullBeard[22] = "Do not shave at all.\n";
    char goatee[33] = "Shave everything but your chin.\n";
    /* Use switch branch for facial hair styles*/
    
    printf("Welcome to Should You Shave!\n");
    printf("Here we will help you decide whether or not you should shave.\n");
    
    printf("\n");
    printf("First things first... do you find facial hair to be uncomfortable? (y/n): \n");
    scanf("%c", &userChoice);
    
    /*Branches*/
    if (userChoice == 'y') {
        printf("\nYou should shave.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else if (userChoice == 'n') {
        printf("\nCool, moving on.\n");
        
        printf("Is it No Shave November? (y/n): \n");
        scanf("%c", &noShaveNovember);
    }
    
    if (noShaveNovember == 'y') {
        printf("Cool, moving on.\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried your program, and it works for me. What environment are you building in?

Comment: I'm working on Xcode. I'm fairly confused cause I just switched from Windows to Mac and have had trouble using Visual Studio (what I was using on Windows) so I've just been using Xcode

Comment: Not sure if this helps but in my terminal the program runs through the first "if-else" statement but once the user is prompted to answer whether or not it is No Shave November (y/n) it immediately ends with exit code: 0

Comment: Try changing `scanf("%c", &noShaveNovember);` to `scanf(" %c", &noShaveNovember);`. Note the space before `%c`. This is needed to skip any newline characters from the previous input.

Comment: Will try that now

Comment: You guys rock, that fixed my problem. Really appreciate it :)

Comment: Do you understand why? is the question... The space in the format string will discard all leading whitespace (generally the `'\n'` left from a prior call to `scanf()`) Which is why input should be done with `fgets()` (and a sufficiently sized buffer) and then parsed with `sscanf()` which ensures a complete line of input is consumed each time...

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you for clarifying that

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `return 0;`  from here:

```
if (userChoice == 'y') {
    printf("\nYou should shave.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And put it here, unless you want the program to end in the first if :

```
if (noShaveNovember == 'y') {
    printf("Cool, moving on.\n");
}
 return 0;
```

}

The `return 0;`  terminates your program so  when you give y as input in first if it terminates.

Also do this :

```
 getchar();
printf("Is it No Shave November? (y/n): \n");
scanf("%c", &noShaveNovember);
if (noShaveNovember == 'y') {
    printf("Cool, moving on.\n");
}
 return 0;
```

Let me explain , we use `getchar();`  in order too get the enter button you press from your keyboard in the first scanf . The enter key is stored in your input and it goes automatically to your next scanf that's why it terminates . **Always use `getchar();`  after your scanf.**

Final version of your programm , working just fine :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    
    char userChoice;
    char noShaveNovember ;
    char participation;
    int numInteractions;
    int voteShave;
    char mustache[36] = "Shave everything but your mustache.\n";
    char fullBeard[22] = "Do not shave at all.\n";y
    char goatee[33] = "Shave everything but your chin.\n";

    /* Use switch branch for facial hair styles*/
    
    printf("Welcome to Should You Shave!\n");
    printf("Here we will help you decide whether or not you should shave.\n");
    
    printf("\n");
    printf("First things first... do you find facial hair to be uncomfortable? (y/n): \n");
    scanf("%c", &userChoice);
    
    /*Branches*/
    if (userChoice == 'y') {
        printf("\nYou should shave.\n");
      
    }
    else if (userChoice == 'n') {
        printf("\nCool, moving on.\n");
      
    }
    getchar();
    printf("Is it No Shave November? (y/n): \n");
    scanf("%c", &noShaveNovember);
    if (noShaveNovember == 'y') {
        printf("Cool, moving on.\n");
    }
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if the user slips and has entered an extra space? `getchar()` alone is insufficient. (very fragile)  It will not handle multiple trailing, or single trailing and single leading or multiple leading whitespace.

Comment: I know that , I thought about mentioning fgets(); , but I decided to give a simple solution and explanation based on his code and not bring in other functions and overcomplicate it. My bad , perhaps I should.

Comment: That's fine, just make sure those assumptions are clear to the person you are answering for who may not yet know that `:)`

Comment: Understood , thank you a lot for your feedback!